# Retrieving data from web with QNetworkAccessManager: the file is downloaded but QNetworkReply::readAll returns null

Tags: c++, qt, qtnetwork

There has been the same question already, but the single answer is not helpful: [Qt Download File - QNetworkAccessManager, not getting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101159/qt-download-file-qnetworkaccessmanager-not-getting-data)

So, I'm trying to download a file:

```
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(QUrl(fileUrl));
QNetworkReply * reply = m_nam.get(request);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onDownloadRequestFinished()), Qt::UniqueConnection);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)), this, SLOT(onDownloadRequestProgress(qint64, qint64)), Qt::UniqueConnection);
```

And in the `onDownloadRequestFinished` slot:

```
QNetworkReply * reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply *>(sender());
if (reply && reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
   Q_ASSERT(reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt() == 200);
   qDebug() << "reply " << reply->bytesAvailable() << reply->pos() << reply->size() << reply->isReadable() << reply->openMode() << reply->isOpen();
}
```

The slot prints the following: `reply  0 0 0 true OpenMode( "ReadOnly" ) true`
So, no data. However, I can clearly see that it does download something somewhere. It's a big file and it does download it, judging from `onDownloadRequestProgress`.

Important clarification: pretty much the same code works in another project on the same computer. I'm trying to find differences, but see none so far.

Where's the data?

Comment: Please check `reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute)` value.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov: I also have `Q_ASSERT(reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt() == 200);`, it never triggers. Update the code to include it.

Comment: Do you see the received data through a network sniffer?

Comment: @peppe: I don't have a sniffer handy, but I'm 100% sure the file _is_ being downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Did you connected *readyRead()* signal to write bytes received into a specific file?

I always did this to save a file:

```
 const QNetworkRequest& request = QNetworkRequest(url);
 reply = qnetworkaccessmanager->get(request);
 QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this,
        SLOT( readingReadyBytes() ));
```

then i create my slot:

```
 void yourClass::readingReadyBytes() {
    file->write(reply->read(reply->bytesAvailable()));
 }
```

Comment: I'll try that but don't think it would make any difference. The basic code that I've specified in the question is correct, since it works in another project.

Comment: It is a bit that I don't develop with QNetworkAccessManager and stuff, so I don't remember very well, but how can you save physically data without readyRead()?

Comment: another way is demonstrated in my question - `finished()` signal and `reply->readAll()`