# QNetworkReply::readAll returns null even though there is no network error

Tags: network-programming, pyqt, qt5, qt5.2

We are developing a Qt5 webkit application which loads html5\javascript\css3 pages. Trying to download a file of size 3MB. But file is downloaded with empty even though there is not network error.

Here's code for the same

```
QNetworkRequest request(url);
QNetworkReply *reply = mNetworkManager->get(request);
QObject::connect(mNetworkManager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this, SLOT(downloadFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

In downloadFinished slot:

```
if (reply->error() != QNetwrkReply::NoError){
    qDebug()<<"download is failed"<< reply->errorString()
}
else {
    QFile file(location);
    if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        file.write(reply->readAll());
    }
}
reply->deleteLater();
```

There is no error reported message but file is created with empty data.That means QNetworkReply->error is QNetworkReply::noError but QNetworkReply::readAll returns NULL.

Could any one tell possibilities for this failure? Any suggestions on fix?

Comment: Are you sure that `QNetworkReply::readAll` really returns empty data? Or you just check the result file contents?

Comment: Yes.. QNetworkReply::readAll returned null since there is no data in the result file.

Comment: Try to check the `readAll()` data itself. Print it to `qDebug`, because you may have problems with writing to `QFile` and not with getting data from `QNetworkReply`.

Comment: Actually our customer has reported this error. From our application logs, I come to know that It was not returned error and there is no issue in opening the file with write only mode. We could only see the empty file. I couldn't reproduce the issue. This issue is seen on Mac 10.9 machine. After goggling i found the threads on similar issue.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/34915  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101159/qt-download-file-
qnetworkaccessmanager-not-getting-data  So I don't have any further clue on this. I need some possibilities to occur this issue.

Comment: What about SSL? Qt uses openSSL 0.9.x libraries from the system in OS X that do not support TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2.

Comment: Url is not a secured site and also no SSL errors are reported. So i assume that there is no issue with SSL.

Comment: Can you publish the download URL to reproduce and check server configuration like HTTP headers?

Comment: I can't publish the URL. This is not reproducible for every one. Even I am also not able to reproduce the issue. One of customers is facing the issue. He is facing the issue on his Mac 10.9 as well as Windows 7 machine. There is no firewall enabled on his machine. I am only suspecting on Proxy settings? Any suggestion?