# Download an excel file as attachment using Qt browser

Tags: qt, download, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

I am working on Qt browser(code taken from [Qt Tab Browser Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebkitexamples-webkitwidgets-browser-webview-cpp.html)). This Qt browser successfully downloads an image file, but not an excel/pdf file. I need to download an excel/pdf file as attachment on click of a button. Excel generation code at back-end uses PHPExcel to generate and finally saves it using 'php://output'.
On browser side, when I read through QNetworkReply's 'readAll()' function, some encoded string '��ࡱ�' gets printed and nothing gets saved in QFile object, totally empty file.

How do I get the desired excel file from this encoded string ?
Please, any help. It is Linux OS and I use LibreOffice if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, got the answer. I was printing QNetworkReply object's content on the console using reply->readAll() before reading it into the file and Qt documentation states that:

> QNetworkReply is a sequential-access QIODevice, which means that once
>   data is read from the object, it no longer kept by the device.

Therefore, i ended up with an empty file. Found this when i printed the size of the 'reply' object. Also, found some eventLoop related help from [here(Roozbeh's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101159/qt-download-file-qnetworkaccessmanager-not-getting-data?rq=1).

Hope it helps someone else as well. Thanks SO !